# glClear is extremely slow when drawableMultisample is set to GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I am developing a drawing app for iOS. I noticed that when i set drawableMultisample to GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X the fps drops from 60 to around 30. I tried to understand what causing this drop in fps and reduced my rendering loop to the following code:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I draw nothing and only perform glClear. With this rendering loop the fps is 37. The same rendering loop with drawableMultisample set to GLKViewDrawableMultisampleNone results in 60 fps.

I am testing in iPad Air.

Is it possible to increase performance when multisampling is enabled?

Comment: You're using EXT_discard_framebuffer?

Comment: Not directly. I am using GLKit - not sure if this command is executed by the framework

Comment: One would hope that it is! You're right to be suspicious I think; I could understand a suddenly increased cost if the system were doing the default thing of preserving the framebuffer between bindings — which means some degree of copying it in and out, hence the discard extension — but if it's not going anywhere and all you're asking for is a clear then this is very suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

iPad Air 1 has a pretty high resolution but the GPU is not really powerfull enough to handle it as you can see in benchmarks like this [one](https://gfxbench.com/result.jsp?benchmark=gfx30&test=546&text-filter=ipad&order=median&ff-desktop=true&ff-lmobile=true&ff-smobile=true&os-Android_gl=true&os-custom_gl=true&os-iOS_gl=true&os-iOS_metal=true&os-OS_X_gl=true&os-Windows_dx=true&os-Windows_gl=true&pu-CPU=true&pu-dGPU=true&pu-iGPU=true&pu-mGPU=true&pu-CPU-iGPU=true&pu-ACC=true&arch-ARM=true&arch-x86=true&base=device), when compared to iPad Air 2 for example (iPad Air 2 being more than 2x faster for the same resolution).

When you enable 4X MSAA, you are telling the GPU to actually render 4x more pixels, so no surprise that you get a performance drop even when just clearing the screen (the MSAA applies to anything, so when clearing the screen I suppose that each pixel cleared is still antialiased)

It is not rare for games on iPads ... not even using MSAA4X ... to run in reduced resolution (ex: 75% / 50%) when they have complex fragment shaders. Note that running at 50% resolution will divide by 4 the number of pixels to process, not by 2 (because you reduce width AND height by 50% => w*0.5*h*0.5 = w*h*0.25)

So you should either :

1. Accept 30fps in native resolution and continue using MSAA4X
2. Run in reduced resolution (ex: 50%) to compensate for MSAA, hoping to still keep 60 fps
3. Disable MSAA and stay in native resolution

Suggestion 2 may feel a bit strange but you should test it, it may actually give you a better quality than 3 ... this all depends how much 60FPS is important for you.

As a final note, I can tell you that most of the complex "AAA" 3D games on IOS I have worked on are not using MSAA at all, we already had enough performance issues without enabling it ... Only on iPhone6 (not 6+ resolution too high) or iPad Air 2 you can eventually consider MSAA if your game already has guaranteed constant 60FPS.